# Почему после завершения работы приложения,таблицы в базе данных становятся пустые?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Вообщем к приложению я подключил базу данных используя её как ресурс,отдельным mdf файлом выглядит это следующим образом.
Строка подключения.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database\Airport.mdf" name="AirportConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Дальше подключаю БД,и ввожу данные.Как только я перезапускаю приложение и подключаюсь заново все данные в таблице flight исчезают.

```
 class Flights_Database
{
    int ID = 1;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder;
    SqlConnection sqlcon;
    internal Flights_Database()
    {          
        string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AirportConnection"].ConnectionString;
        sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);          
    }
    internal SqlConnection Sqlcon
    {
        get
        {
            return sqlcon;
        }
        set
        {
            sqlcon = value;
        }
    }
    internal static DateTime EnterData()
    {
        int year;
        int day;
        int month;
        int hour;
        int minute;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Year=");
                year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter Month=");
                month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter day=");
                day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter Hour=");
                hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter Minute=");
                minute = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong value try again");
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    internal static int countrows()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    internal void Add_Flight()
    {
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        SqlCommand addflight = new SqlCommand();
        addflight.Connection =Sqlcon;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Arrival Date");
        flight.Arrival = EnterData();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Departure Date");
        flight.Departure = EnterData();
        Console.Write("Enter Flight number=");
        flight.Flight_Number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter City of arrival=");
        flight.City_of_arrival = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter City of departure=");
        flight.City_of_Departure = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Terminal=");
        flight.Terminal = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Flight status=");
        flight.Flight_Status = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Gate=");
        flight.ID = ID;
        flight.Gate= Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        addflight.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Flights(Arrival,Departure,Flight_Number,City_of_arrival,City_of_departure,Terminal,Flight_Status,Gate,ID)";
        addflight.CommandText += " VALUES(@Arrival, @Departure, @Flight_Number, @City_of_arrival, @City_of_departure, @Terminal, @Flight_Status, @Gate, @ID)";
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrival",flight.Arrival);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departure", flight.Departure);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flight_Number", flight.Flight_Number);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_of_arrival", flight.City_of_arrival);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_of_departure", flight.City_of_Departure);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terminal",flight.Terminal);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flight_Status", flight.Flight_Status);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gate", flight.Gate);
        addflight.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID);
        ID++;
        try
        {
            addflight.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlcon.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }   

    }

}
```

Пока приложение работает,в таблицы можно добавлять данные,удалять,а также выводить на экран,как только работа приложения завершается,все данные в таблице обнуляются.
Соединение закрываю следующей командой `flights.Sqlcon.Close();` .Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Я разобрался частично,данные в таблице удаляются когда я запускаю заново приложение и отрываю соединение командой Open.С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Уберите скриншот, на котором ни черта не видно - и приведите правильно оформленный код.

Comment: Исправил,так вопрос понятнее звучит?

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Если БД затирается - ее кто-то затирает. Ищите кто.

Comment: У вас данные из БД пропадают сразу после закрытия приложения? Как вы определяете, что они пропали?

Comment: Скорее всего БД просто затирается новым экземпляром при компиляции. Попробуйте указать в свойствах mdf файла "Не копировать", а сам файл скопировать в папку Dedug, один раз, вручную.

Comment: `sqlcon.Close();` должно быть в блоке не в блоке `try`, а в блоке `finally` (добавьте его).

Comment: Данные пропадают не сразу после закрытия,а после того как я запускаю приложение заново,и устанавливаю соединение с базой данных.Определяю что они пропали я через Server exploler,там можно посмотреть что внутри таблиц.

Comment: Mirdin правильно подсказал,проблема решена,спасибо всем за помощь